# how to invoke listview setAdapter automatically after add new item

Tags: android, listview

I have a button to add new item to **listA**:

```
listView.setAdpater(xx, xx ,listA);
```

But I have to invoke:
`listView.setAdpater(xx, xx ,listA);` on the `OnClickListener` so that the data can be seen on screen. 
How can I do this a better way?

Comment: you can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in the OnClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

This notifies the `listview` that the adapter data has changed

Comment: no notifyDataSetChanged in getAdapter() . only methods "notify" and "notifyAll()"

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using? `ListAdapters` don't have the method `nofifyDataSetChanged`. Maybe try `(BaseAdapter)listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` or `(ArrayAdapter)listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` or typecast it to whatever kind of adapter you are using

Comment: One more question, after add new item to the data(list<String>) of adapter, the adapter is not new? The reason is invoke listView.setAdapter again like call notifyDataSetChanged ? Do you know what's the different?

Comment: No the adapter is not new. The method `notiftDataSetChanged` is telling the adapter that the listview's data has changed. The adapter is the connection between the data in the listview and the what is shown in the listview- the ui component. So there is no need to created a new adapter.